# Has vs Have which to use

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

The Sentence is

> The way computers has invaded our society is remarkable.

now, when I tried to use Ginger Grammar in this sentence it has suggested to use 
**have** instead of **has**... making the sentence look like this

> The way computers have invaded our society is remarkable.

Now, my teacher has told the class that the first sentence is **Good**. how can that be? she told us that the noun in the sentence is **way**, and the sentence could stand alone without the word **Computer**, I told her that the sentence could not stand without a the word **computer** because there would be a question in the sentence **asking**: *What has invaded in the society?*

she then defended, *it's not **what** but **who***. I got blank at that point.. and agreed to here answer, to finish the class.

Comment: You're right, she's wrong. *The way* is the singular subject of *is remarkable*, but *computers h-- invaded our society* is a distinct subordinate clause whose subject is plural *computers*. The *who/what* distinction is irrelevant (but she's wrong about that, too).

Comment: a re-ordering is revealing: << Computers have/*has invaded our society in a way that is remarkable. >>

Answer (score 1):

The form of the verb **has** is only used in the third person singular. All other forms are **have**. Since **computers** is a plural subject (in third person plural), you should use **have**. This is where it's important to know who or what is doing the action. If a single computer was doing it the sentence would be "The way that the computer **has** invaded our society is remarkable".